# Hamiltonian Constant on integral curves

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics

Let $H \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and let $(x(t),y(t))$ be a solution to the equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} H(x(t),y(t))$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} H(x(t),y(t))$$
I need to show that $H$ is constant along $(x(t), y(t))$. How would I do so using only the information **[here](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.101/fa14/documents/anal-notes-12.pdf)**?

Moreover, does $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}$$ have a well-defined meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the chain rule and use the differential equation.

$$
\frac{d}{dt}H(x(t),y(t)) = \partial_x H(x(t),y(t)) \frac{dx}{dt} + \partial_y H(x(t),y(t)) \frac{dy}{dt}
$$

Now use the equation to get:

$$
\partial_x H(x(t),y(t)) \partial_y H(x(t),y(t)) - \partial_y H(x(t),y(t)) \partial_x H(x(t),y(t)) = 0 
$$

So the function $H$ is constant along the curve $(x(t),y(t))$.